# Sending csv file from Apple Watch to Phone - nothing happening

Tags: swift, apple-watch

I have this function in the `Watchkit Extension`'s `InterfaceController`...

```
func createAndSendCSV(data: Array<String>) {

    var csvText = "time, data\n"
    let fileName = "\(startTime).csv"
    let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    for row in data {
        csvText += row
    }

    do {
        try csvText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        WCSession.default.transferFile(path!, metadata: ["time": startTime])
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create file")
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

that is called when the user stops the app on the watch.  I know the function is triggered because I can add a print statement in the do catch showing that it was successful.

On `ViewController` I have the below which isn't much beyond making sure the session is activated and then trying to work with the file that was sent. I don't see any errors but I also don't see my print test message.

I'm trying to use a CSV file to transfer data as I can't send via sendMessage due to size of message. Anyone know why it might not be working?

```
import UIKit
import WatchConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        let session = WCSession.default
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceive file: WCSessionFile) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        do {
            print("test")
            let contents = try String(contentsOf: file.fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
            self.sendData(data: contents)
        } catch {
            print("File Read Error for file \(String(describing: file.metadata))")
        }
    }
}

func sendData(data: String) {
    print(data)
}

// Not used but needs to exist
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {

}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {

}

func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using `transferFile(_:metadata:)` runs asynchronously and gets throttled by the system to accommodate Apple Watch’s limits on performance and power. You should be able to check the status of the 
[outstandingFileTransfers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615641-outstandingfiletransfers) property to ensure you are setting up the transfer correctly, but beyond that you may need to rethink how you are sharing data between the two devices.

Comment: I don't really see any other way to transfer the data besides trying to send it as a file given data size limits (and it's not a lot - less than 1mb. Not really clear on why it would be throttling either.  I'll see what I can do

Comment: How did you transfer files 1 mb from watch to iOS app?